# Why do I suddenly get an invalidRequest when using the Microsoft Graph Api route GET /sites/{site-id}/pages?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sites

GET /sites/{site-id}/pages

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{my-site-id}/pages
stopped working for me end of last week. I am getting the following error

{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "badArgument",
            "request-id": "f292e4b5-a4a4-43f6-8e5b-20979eeddb0c",
            "date": "2020-04-22T12:09:30"
        }
    }
}

I am certain my request is correct since it worked perfectly fine before. The current version of the doku (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sitepage-list?view=graph-rest-beta) also agrees that I am using the correct route.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on with this beta feature?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the site-id using the "{hostname},{spsite-id},{spweb-id}" syntax is successful for me.

Ex. 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{hostnameRemoved},646dd80e-8889-43c2-8575-efc2208458b6,6ca05f4b-d2e7-41bc-98be-4792b9bd6c55/pages

Specifying the site-id using the "{hostname}:{serverRelativePath}" syntax is throwing an error for me though.

Ex.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{hostnameRemoved}:/sites/{siteNameRemoved}:/pages

{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Provided identifier is malformed - site collection id is not valid",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2474838b-1c5a-4155-bdfb-ff9778fc42e6",
            "date": "2020-04-25T01:44:31"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Unfortunate https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{hostnameRemoved},646dd80e-8889-43c2-8575-efc2208458b6,6ca05f4b-d2e7-41bc-98be-4792b9bd6c55/pages does not seem to work either.
Interestingly though we did get a result when using the route for a specific page https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{hostnameRemoved},646dd80e-8889-43c2-8575-efc2208458b6,6ca05f4b-d2e7-41bc-98be-4792b9bd6c55/pages/{some-guid}

Comment: Do you have a request-id and timestamp from either or both of the most recent test cases?

Comment: Sure, I retested just now (URL:  graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites{hostnameRemoved},6ff04023-a112-437c-8c2f-ae18233af960,726a940e-cfda-4569-9a67-9544230bcea0/pages)

          
"request-id": "77e88577-7627-4e65-b1c1-469651d840c1",
 "date": "2020-05-04T05:16:30"

Comment: Thanks.  Ensure that the query to the site (removing "/pages") returns a valid response.  I've seen issues where the site-id is malformed and thus any further queries to sub-elements also fail.  The above test shows an HTTP 400 error for badArgument so might be related.

Comment: I think the site-id is fine. I can get the result for a specific page by appending a page guide after /pages (graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites{hostnameRemoved},646dd80e-8889-43c2-8575-efc2208458b6,6ca05f4b-d2e7-41bc-98be-4792b9bd6c55/pages/{some-guid}). It really only seems to be not working when I want all pages.